# When is it worth using `data.table`? When can I expect the largest performance gains?

Tags: r, data.table

I just spent some time researching about `data.table` in R and was wondering about the conditions under which I can expect the largest performance gains. Maybe the simple answer is when I have a large data.frame and often operate on subsets of this data.frame. When I just load data files and estimate models I can't expect much but many `[` operations make the difference. Is that true and the only answer or what else should I consider? When does it start to matter? 10x5, 1,000x5, 1,000,000x5?

Edit: Some of the comments suggest that `data.table` is often faster and, equally important, almost never slower. So it would also be good to know when not to use `data.table`.

Comment: A great (if broad) question. Ideally this would be answered by pointing to the timings vignette ([latest version here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-timings.pdf)), but at this point it's quite undeveloped. I'm sure, though, that Matthew Dowle would appreciate help with it or some similar document!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that using a `data.table` is probably never slower than using a `data.frame` (if you find a case, I bet it will get patched quickly).  In addition to speed of calculation, a `data.table` solution will probably take fewer keystrokes.

Comment: Because what GSee says is true in my experience, and in general data.table inherits from data.frame, I think the question could be better posed as when *not* to use data.table.  The only thing I have wanted to do with it that I could not is use rbind.fill()

Comment: Great comments, great answers so far! franks, I will add that point to my questions

Comment: @frankc +1 But what's the issue with `rbind.fill`?  This works fine for me: `rbind.fill(as.data.table(mtcars[c("mpg", "wt")]), as.data.table(mtcars[c("wt", "cyl")]))`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are at least a few cases where `data.table` shines:

- Updating an existing dataset with new results.  Because `data.table` is by-reference, this is [massively faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486369/growing-a-data-frame-in-a-memory-efficient-manner/11486400#11486400).
- Split-apply-combine type strategies with large numbers of groups to split over (as @PaulHiemstra's answer points out).
- Doing almost anything to a truly large dataset.

Here are some benchmarks:
[Benchmarking data.frame (base), data.frame(package dataframe) and data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721615/benchmarking-data-frame-base-data-framepackage-dataframe-and-data-table/10721803#10721803)

Answer (score 7):

One instance where `data.table` is veeeery fast is in the split-apply-combine type of work which made `plyr` famous. Say you have a `data.frame` with the following data:

```
precipitation     time   station_id
23.3              1      A01
24.1              2      A01
26.1              1      A02
etc etc
```

When you need to average per station id, you can use a host of R functions, e.g. `ave`, `ddply`, or `data.table`. If the number of unique elements in `station_id` grows, `data.table` scales really well, whilst e.g. `ddply` get's really slow. More details, including an example, can be found in [this post on my blog](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/10/28/comparison-of-ave-ddply-and-data-table/). This test suggests that speed increases of more than 150 fold are possible. This difference can probably be much bigger...

Comment: The next iteration of `plyr`, `dplyr`, will be fighting back (performance wise).  Should be 10-100x faster, and within a factor of 10 of the speed of `data.table`. (All using pure R too).  It will also let you use `data.table` as a backend, so you can have the best of both worlds.

Comment: That souds awesome! When will it be released?

Comment: Yes, sounds awesome! Where are the gains coming from? And how does the integration with `data.table` work? An option for the backend or based on the passed arguments?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra in the next 6 months, all going well. The gains come from specialising the most common parts of plyr (e.g. ddply + subset/summarise/mutate/arrange) and minimising the number of intermediate subsets of the data frame that are made. It will also support SQL databases as a backend.